# How to process a somewhat big CSV file in firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, csv, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to process(read) a csv file(15MB) in firebase functions?
If so what can I do to offload a somewhat gigantic task(parallel or whatever is the term).

My flow is like this, i read a row of CSV and extract an email, then after getting the email, I'll update the firebase firestore of the corresponding user and then let the CSV be downloaded(pipe to a response).

I got it to work on the response(file.createReadStream.pipe to response), but I can't find a way wrap my head on how to process such a large CSV file that would have hundreds of thousands of rows.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Cloud Functions isn't suitable for "gigantic" units of work.  The default time a function may run is 1 minute, and the max (by config) is 9 minutes.  If that's not enough time, you can't do it with Cloud Functions without somehow decomposing the work.  If you can't decompose the work into smaller discrete units, consider alternatives that let you run a long-running task, such as App Engine or Compute Engine.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, thanks for your reply, okay. 

But if I limit my csv rows to say only a hundred is it doable?

if so what should be my flow?

Comment: The question is a bit broad but it sounds like you are reading a single line from an CSV file to obtain an email address and then doing something with the rest of the file - perhaps uploading it to Firebase Storage so the user can then download it? What kind of *processing* are you doing on the CSV file - row by row? Or just uploading the whole file or something else entirely?

Comment: read the csv file, extract the email contained row by row, then after pipe it to the response to be downloaded @jay

Comment: The question is vague; where is the file stored? Locally? In Storage? Somewhere else? You want to read the file by line and extract an email; does your app do that? Are you expecting Firebase functions to parse a .csv file? Do you have some other mechanism? Once you have the email, what data are you piping; That row, the whole file? How does Firebase fit into this? As you can see, there's really not enough information in the question to understand the use case. Please review the following guide on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)